# How to insert metadata in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to insert some metadata (i.e. keywords, description, author) inside my web pages created by Sphinx.

I found

```
:fieldname: Field content
```

in the documentation of Sphinx, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: I already figure out. There is a directive called "meta", which perfectly meets my desire.

You can find it here: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#meta

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I already figure out. There is a directive called "meta", which perfectly meets my desire.

You can find it here: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#meta

Comment: Where did you insert the meta directive? I've tried inserting it both above and below the page header, but the Sphinx HTML output does not translate the directive into HTML meta tags.

e.g.:

    .. meta::
       :description: Useful topic
       :keywords: plaintext, markup language
    
    ********************************************************************************
    Page title
    ********************************************************************************
    
    .. meta::
       :description: Useful topic
       :keywords: plaintext, markup language

Comment: @Mark I inserted `meta` below the title of the page: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxks-kkk/old_web/120890ca33938cee7a17eaa65e7f3df3dd54b1bc/web2/index.rst However, I haven't used `meta` a lot since 2012. If the above example doesn't work, you can try to hack the jinja template and directly add meta information into your template. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @zack! 

Further research reveals someone on our team removed the {{ metatags }} variable from our layout.html file sometime in the past. Restoring it restored support for the .. meta directive.

Comment: @Mark Glad to hear that :)